# Issue with Preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I make a simple application to take recipe info from websites like `allrecipes.com.` I'm using `preg_match`, but something is not working.

```
$geturl = file_get_contents("http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Brown-Sugar-Smokies/Detail.aspx?src=rotd");
          preg_match('#<title>(.*) - Allrecipes.com</title>#', $geturl, $match);
          $name = $match[1];
          echo $name;
```

I'm just trying to take the title of the page (minus the `- Allrecipes.com` part) and put it into a variable, but all that turns up is blank.

Comment: Have you tried printing `$geturl` and seeing if the string is, in fact, there?

Comment: You are missing to troubleshoot your code. For example, check return values before you use them.

Comment: @minitech, Yeah when I print `$geturl`, I get the entire Allrecipes.com page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems in this pattern. First, there was a newline symbol after the `<title>` which wasn't captured by `.` (as without `/s` modifier `.` is literally 'any symbol but EOL one'). Second, the `Allrecipes.com` text was actually NOT followed by `</title>` substring, there was a newline separating them.

Taking into account the fact that `\s` covers both normal whitespace and line separating one, you can just alter your regex like this:

```
'#<title>\s*(.*?) - Allrecipes.com\s*</title>#s'
```

`/s` modifier is not actually relevant here (cudos to minitech for noticing that), as the title in this recipe is one-line, and all "\n" symbols will be covered by `\s*` subexpression. But I'd still suggest leaving it there, so that multi-line titles won't catch you off-guard.

I've replaced `.*` with `.*?` for efficiency sake here: as the string you're looking for is quite short, it makes sense to use non-greedy quantifier here.

Comment: `</title>` doesn’t immediately follow `Allrecipes.com`, either.

Comment: Why is the `s` modifier relevant now, though? There aren’t newlines *within* the recipe name.

Comment: You're right, of course; I though that common `". is not a \n"` problem is the only issue here, when in fact the OP should have covered the padding before `</title>` as well in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source of the page, you'll notice that `<title>` contains some padding around the actual text, for which you need to compensate.

```
'#<title>\s*(.*) - Allrecipes.com\s*</title>#'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get whole title first, then strip it using PHP, like so:

```
<?php

$raw_html=file_get_contents('http://www.allrecipes.com');
if (empty($raw_html)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Fetch empty');
}

$matches=array();
if (preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/s', $raw_html, $matches) === false) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Regex error');
}

$title=trim($matches[1]);

// you should strip your title here
echo $title;
```